# emacs style keyboard macros in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, macros

I'd like to use emacs style keyboard macros in Visual Studio, which for the most part I can do through these [shortcut mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165522(VS.80).aspx)... but I can't figure out a keyboard shortcut to repeat the next command x times.  In emacs, I could record my macro, then type

Esc, #, ctrl+x, e

where # is the number of times I want to repeat my macro.  In my view, this was almost as important as the macro itself.  How can  achieve this in Visual Studio?

Comment: let me give you my tip to achieve that (that's what I do): Install emacs. Right click your source tab, select `open containing folder`, then right click your file and "open with emacs". M-g goto  your line and do your stuff. no replacement for emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna try XKeymacs:

http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html

I have tried your sequence and it kind of worked on a simple macro.
However, it was quite slow... Anyway, give it a shot.

Comment: That works nicely, although you are right, it is quite slow.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I tested it first with notepad.  It doesn't work quite as well in Visual Studio... I think the intellitype stuff might be getting in the way, as it seems to work about half the time just for normal macros, and not so well for the escape repeat.
Another problem was that escape repeat could only work for #'s less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

For that functionality you have to write your own macro, but yo'll be not able to use that shortcut, only pairs are supported...